# Load empty/optional embedded hasMany relation with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Where most people have problems loading embedded Ember models, I have a problem with the exact opposite.

Ember throws errors when I try to parse a record that contains an `embedded` relationship, where the content for that `hasMany` relation is an empty array.

**How do you make an embedded Ember Data hasMany relation optional or nullable?**

I have a model..

```
App.Beat = DS.Model.extend({

  notes: DS.hasMany('note', {
    embedded: 'always', 
    defaultValue: []
  }),

  ...
})
```

This model is an association in a `Bar` model, which is an association in a `Track` model. Those don't really matter here.

These embedded `hasMany` relationships get serialized with the following serializer..

```
// http://bl.ocks.org/slindberg/6817234
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

  // Extract embedded relations from the payload and load them into the store
  normalizeRelationships: function(type, hash) {
    var store = this.store;

    this._super(type, hash);

    type.eachRelationship(function(attr, relationship) {
      var relatedTypeKey = relationship.type.typeKey;

      if (relationship.options.embedded) {
        if (relationship.kind === 'hasMany') {
          hash[attr] = hash[attr].map(function(embeddedHash) {
            // Normalize the record with the correct serializer for the type
            var normalized = store.serializerFor(relatedTypeKey).normalize(relationship.type, embeddedHash, attr);

            // If the record has no id, give it a GUID so relationship management works
            if (!normalized.id) {
              normalized.id = Ember.generateGuid(null, relatedTypeKey);
            }

            // Push the record into the store
            store.push(relatedTypeKey, normalized);

            // Return just the id, and the relation manager will take care of the rest
            return normalized.id;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

After successfully deserializing and loading the records in the store, somewhere in the application the `bars` property on a `Track` gets accessed. If that `Bar` has `beats` of which one of those `beats` do not have any `notes` (because it is a rest beat where no notes get played) then the following error is thrown:

> "You looked up the 'bars' relationship on '' but some of the associated records were not loaded. Either make sure they are all loaded together with the parent record, or specify that the relationship is async (DS.hasMany({ async: true }))"

This error comes from the following assertion in ember-data.js:hasRelationship:

```
Ember.assert("...", Ember.A(records).everyProperty('isEmpty', false));
```

where `records` is the array of `bars` that contain beats that optionally contains `notes`.

So, **how do I make an `embedded` `hasMany` relation *optional* so that it accepts an empty array of records?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned our that it was the `isEmpty` on my `bar` model that conflicted with the property that was being tested in the Ember assertation. Renaming this property made everything work.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the `EmbeddedRecordsMixin` in a recent Ember Data beta (10 or 11) and then see if you still have an issue with embedded records.

Your application serializer:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
   // probably nothing required here yet
});
```

And then in your Beat model serializer:

```
App.BeatSerializer = App.ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    notes: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
});
```

Comment: upgraded from 1.0.0.7 to 1.0.0.11, and refactored to the EmbeddedRecordsMixin, but the problems persists.